# Can we generate arbitrary numbers in Julia?

Tags: random, julia

I am curious to know if it is possible to generate an **arbitrary** number in Julia. That is, a number that does not follow any particular distribution. If I use `x=rand()`, then I am afraid that `x` is uniformly distributed between `[0,1]`.

Comment: If you want to generate a pseudorandom number it will follow some distribution. Therefore the question is what is the type (data type, e.g. `Float64`, `Int64` etc.) of result that you want and what is the expected distribution. Then your question can be meaningfully answered. For instance Distributions.jl defines a wide range of target distributions you might want to sample from.

Comment: This question is not answerable unless you define what you mean by *arbitrary* in this context.

Comment: Do you think of "arbitrary" as "generated using a random distribution"? If so, a uniform distribution is what you want, since choosing a number from a uniform distribution is the same as choosing a random distrubtion out of the distribution space and then choosing a random number from that distribution.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński, I would like to generate a random number (data type `Float64`), not a pseudorandom one. In fact, I am using `Distributions.jl` to generate (for example) uniform random number using `rand(Uniform(0, 1))`. Now, I would like to generate a random number using a random number generator (a number that cannot be predicted or that does not follow any particular distributions). I used simply `rand(0, 1)` but I am afraid that `rand(0,1)` will return a  uniform random number as `rand(Uniform(0, 1))` does.

Comment: Then it is simplest to use `RandomDevice()` or fetch randomness from outside source, e.g. http://www.random.org/. You can then use e.g. `HTTP` package to fetch data from this service (this is probably a bit slow and there is a daily limit).

Comment: There is no such thing as a random (or pseudorandom) number that does not follow any particular distribution. Random number (including "truly" random numbers) are sampled from a distribution, whether this is the uniform distribution from 0 to 1 or the gaussian-like distribution from a number of different physical phenomena or any other distribution. There is also cryptographically secure pseudo random numbers, which might be what you want, but those as well follow a distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean any number in the range representable by a type?

```
julia> function rand_in(T)
         rand()*(typemax(T)-typemin(T))+typemin(T)
       end
rand_in (generic function with 1 method)

julia> x=rand_in(Int32)
-2.147483648237874e9
```

EDIT: re-wrote function according to comments of @Nico202
EDIT2:re-wrote function according to comments of @Nico202

Comment: This code will not produce the result you describe in general because `rand()` produces only 52 bits of randomness. Also the code would produce sensible results only if `T<:Union{Bool, Signed, Unsigned}`.

Comment: Why an anonymous function instead of 
```rand_in(T) = rand()*(typemax(T)-typemin(T))+typemin(T)```? Yours is 100x slower ( 4.482 ns vs 457.490 ns)

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński You're right. Do you have any suggestions to improve the code? From where I'm sitting, it looks too complicated and I'm still not sure of what  is being asked for

Comment: Exactly - when @zdm specifies what is needed one can reasonably help. The specification entails: data type of generated result (this is related to number of bits of randomness that are required) and required distribution. If one wants to generate `Float64` uniformly over some interval what you propose is the way to go. This is exactly what Distributions.jl for `Uniform` type does: https://github.com/JuliaStats/Distributions.jl/blob/master/src/univariate/continuous/uniform.jl#L109.

Comment: @Nico202 while the anonymous function is probably bad style here, it will compile to the same function as the generic function on Julia v0.5 and above and will have exactly the same timing.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas I thought the same but while with @ time I get the same allocations, with BenchmarkTools.@ btime I got these timings, so I don't know what to trust

Comment: It's probably just because it's not specializing. Julia doesn't auto-specialize Datatype inputs on anonymous functions IIRC. I think you can force it via `(::Type{T}) where T -> ...` or something like that.

Comment: Thanks. However, I still think that giving names to anonymous functions is "wrong" :D